# jQuery.each - Getting li elements inside an ul

Tags: jquery, each

I have this HTML on my page:

```
<div class="phrase">
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="agap"><ul><li>TEXT1</li></ul></li>
        <li class="agap"><ul>  </ul></li> <!-- empty ul -->
        <li class="aword">TEXT2</li>
        ..
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="phrase"> ... </div>
```

I would like to get for each "phrase" all the elements in "items" in a text variable, like this:

```
var string = "TEXT1 - BLANK - TEXT2";
```

I currently have this javascript code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.phrase .items').each(function(){
        var myText = "";

        // At this point I need to loop all li items and get the text inside
        // depending on the class attribute

        alert(myText);

    });
};
</script>
```

How can I iterate all `<li>` inside `.items`?

I was trying different ways but I didn't get good results.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First I think you need to fix your lists, as the first node of a `<ul>` must be a `<li>` ([stackoverflow ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209699/does-everything-inside-a-ul-have-to-be-wrapped-in-an-li)). Once that is setup you can do this:

```
// note this array has outer scope
var phrases = [];

$('.phrase').each(function(){
        // this is inner scope, in reference to the .phrase element
        var phrase = '';
        $(this).find('li').each(function(){
            // cache jquery var
            var current = $(this);
            // check if our current li has children (sub elements)
            // if it does, skip it
            // ps, you can work with this by seeing if the first child
            // is a UL with blank inside and odd your custom BLANK text
            if(current.children().size() > 0) {return true;}
            // add current text to our current phrase
            phrase += current.text();
        });
        // now that our current phrase is completely build we add it to our outer array
        phrases.push(phrase);
    });
    // note the comma in the alert shows separate phrases
    alert(phrases);
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DdjSN/).

One thing is if you get the `.text()` of an upper level `li` you will get all sub level text with it.

Keeping an array will allow for many multiple phrases to be extracted.

---

**EDIT:**

This should work better with an empty `UL` with no `LI`:

```
// outer scope
var phrases = [];

$('.phrase').each(function(){
    // inner scope
    var phrase = '';
    $(this).find('li').each(function(){
        // cache jquery object
        var current = $(this);
        // check for sub levels
        if(current.children().size() > 0) {
            // check is sublevel is just empty UL
            var emptyULtest = current.children().eq(0); 
            if(emptyULtest.is('ul') && $.trim(emptyULtest.text())==""){
                phrase += ' -BLANK- '; //custom blank text
                return true;   
            } else {
             // else it is an actual sublevel with li's
             return true;   
            }
        }
        // if it gets to here it is actual li
        phrase += current.text();
    });
    phrases.push(phrase);
});
// note the comma to separate multiple phrases
alert(phrases);
```

Comment: This is working for me, but I need to know when ul has no li, so, in this case I should get "BLANK" as text. Maybe my post was not clear at all. 
I don't understand this line:
if(current.children().size() > 0) {return true;}

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, that technically isn't valid markup. But you can work with it using that line. I'll update my answer with some clarifying comments -- it is now updated!.

Comment: I edited my question. I will never ul with extrange code. Only ul with li or <ul></ul>

Comment: Okie dokie -- added a second function and updated the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 10):

```
$(function() {
    $('.phrase .items').each(function(i, items_list){
        var myText = "";

        $(items_list).find('li').each(function(j, li){
            alert(li.text());
        })

        alert(myText);

    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an answer as high voted and views. I did find the answer with mixed of here and other links.

I have a scenario where all patient-related menu is disabled if a patient is not selected. (Refer link - [how to disable a li tag using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004734/how-to-disable-a-li-tag-using-javascript))

```
//css
.disabled{
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity:0.4;
}
// jqvery
$("li a").addClass('disabled');
// remove .disabled when you are done
```

So rather than write long code, I found an interesting solution via CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var PatientId ; 
 //var PatientId =1;  //remove to test enable i.e. patient selected
 if (typeof PatientId == "undefined" || PatientId == "" || PatientId == 0 || PatientId == null) {
  console.log(PatientId);
  $("#dvHeaderSubMenu a").each(function () {   
   $(this).addClass('disabled');
  });  
  return;
 }
})
```

```css
.disabled{
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dvHeaderSubMenu">
     <ul class="m-nav m-nav--inline pull-right nav-sub">
      <li class="m-nav__item">
       <a href="#" onclick="console.log('PatientMenu Clicked')" >
        <i class="m-nav__link-icon fa fa-tachometer"></i>
        Overview
       </a>
      </li>

      <li class="m-nav__item active">
       <a href="#" onclick="console.log('PatientMenu Clicked')" >
        <i class="m-nav__link-icon fa fa-user"></i>
        Personal
       </a>
      </li>
            <li class="m-nav__item m-dropdown m-dropdown--inline m-dropdown--arrow" data-dropdown-toggle="hover">
       <a href="#" class="m-dropdown__toggle dropdown-toggle" onclick="console.log('PatientMenu Clicked')">
        <i class="m-nav__link-icon flaticon-medical-8"></i>
        Insurance Claim
       </a>
       <div class="m-dropdown__wrapper">
        <span class="m-dropdown__arrow m-dropdown__arrow--left"></span>
        
           <ul class="m-nav">
            <li class="m-nav__item">
             <a href="#" class="m-nav__link" onclick="console.log('PatientMenu Clicked')" >
              <i class="m-nav__link-icon flaticon-toothbrush-1"></i>
              <span class="m-nav__link-text">
               Primary
              </span>
             </a>
            </li>
            <li class="m-nav__item">
             <a href="#" class="m-nav__link" onclick="console.log('PatientMenu Clicked')">
              <i class="m-nav__link-icon flaticon-interface"></i>
              <span class="m-nav__link-text">
               Secondary
              </span>
             </a>
            </li>
            <li class="m-nav__item">
             <a href="#" class="m-nav__link" onclick="console.log('PatientMenu Clicked')">
              <i class="m-nav__link-icon flaticon-healthy"></i>
              <span class="m-nav__link-text">
               Medical
              </span>
             </a>
            </li>
           </ul>
          
       
      </li>
     </ul>            
</div>
```