# how to disable a li tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following HTML on my page:

```
<ul id="tabnav">

        <li id="tab_a" class="tab1"><a href="tab1.htm">Tab a</a></li>
        <li id="tab_b" class="tab2"><a href="tab2.htm">Tab b</a></li>
        <li id="tab_c" class="tab3"><a href="tab3.htm">Tab c</a></li>
    </ul>
```

What I am trying to do is make it so that you can't click on the 3rd tab using javascript then I want to be able to click on the 3rd tab at a later time.

So I have tried using the following JavaScript in a JavaScript function:

```
document.getElementById("tab_c").style.enabled = false;
```

however it didn't seem to work.

I was hoping that it would make it disabled so you can't click on it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's something you aren't telling us.  `li` items have no default click handler.

Comment: I suppose you mean disabling the `<a>` rather than `<li>`.

Comment: @AlvinWong - I am using the tab css from http://unraveled.com/publications/assets/css_tabs/index.html and I want to be able to disable one of the tabs then be able to re-enable it again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add an onclick handler to the link that returns false.

```
document.getElementById("tab_c").childNodes[0].onclick = function() {return false;};​
```

*The `childNodes[0]` just selects the first child which in this case is the `<a>`*

E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/zYSeF/

Comment: I guess I can use this.. but I was hoping to disable one of my tabs.. I am using this css tab and was hoping to disable one of the tabs then re-enable it again - http://unraveled.com/publications/assets/css_tabs/index.html

Comment: @Aaron Since that is done completely with css, this is your best option.  There is no way to disable something that can't be disabled in the first place.

Comment: @Daedalus Thanks, that explains why I can't do it.. I will just have to go with this then.

Comment: @Aaron You can just have your disable/enable function do both. Add/remove a CSS class to style the tab correctly, and use the above JS to actually disable it :)

Comment: @AdamHeath- How can I hide the same li?

Answer (score 29):

```
//css
.disabled{
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity:0.4;
}
// jqvery
$("li a").addClass('disabled');
// remove .disabled when you are done
```

Comment: +1 for the perfect answer, after some medication at my end I am able to disable all li and nested li too.

Answer (score 5):

Using the jQuery library, you can do something like this.

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    return !$(this).attr('disabled');
});
```

To toggle being disabled, you can simply do this.

```
$('#tab_c a').attr('disabled', true); //add
$('#tab_c a').removeAttr('disabled'); //remove
```

**[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)**

Comment: Rather do it JavaScript. I can't use any jQuery for this.

Comment: @Aaron jQuery **is** javascript.

Comment: I understand that, but it requires a 100kb+ file and when I use it on my device I am going to use it for, it takes to long to load and when I don't use this jQuery file it loads a lot faster. I rather do it with jQuery but I can't with this.