# Unable to disable `<li>` elements by setting `disable` property to `true`

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to make the rest of my chat room app disabled while a modal is open. I've been using `element.disable = true` to disable the buttons and this has worked. I have a `ul` where each `li` is the name of a chat room that is clickable and opens up its respective chat room in another container. I'm trying to disable the `li`s using the same `disable.true` method. I'm using a `for` loop to iterate through the array of `li`s, but it isn't working.

I used `console.log` to view the variable with the array stored in it (`var lis`) as well as the `console.log(lis.length)`. The console shows that the array has a length of 5 but returns `lis.length` as 0.

Would be much appreciated if someone could tell me what I'm doing incorrectly.

HTML:

```
<div class"home-template" id="home">
  <div class="rooms-container">
    <h1 class="app-title">Bloc Chat</h1>
    <ul id="rooms-list">
      <li class="room-item" id="room-item" ng-repeat="chat in home.chatRooms">
        <a href="#" class="room-link" id="{{ chat.$value }}" data-ng-click="home.getRoomName(chat.$id)">{{ chat.$value }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="new-room-button" type="button" ng-click="home.open()">New room</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="delete-cookies-button" type="button" ng-click="home.deleteCookies()">Delete Cookie for testing</button>
  </div>
  <div class="messages-container">
    <h1 class="current-room" ng-bind="home.activeRoom"></h1>
    <ul class="messages-list">
      <li class="message-bubble" ng-repeat="message in home.messages">
        <div class="username">{{ message.username }}</div>
        <div class="sentAt">{{ message.sentAt }}</div>
        <div class="content">{{ message.content }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript in a `home` controller:

```
home.cookieDisplay = $cookies.get('blocChatCurrentUser');
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
var lis = document.getElementsByClassName('room-item');
var newButton = document.getElementById('new-room-button');
var delButton = document.getElementById('delete-cookies-button');
if (modals.length === 0) {
  newButton.disabled = false;
  delButton.disabled = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].disabled.false;
  }
} else if (modals.length !== 0) {
    newButton.disabled = true;
    delButton.disabled = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
      // lis[i].setAttribute('display', 'none');
      lis[i].disabled.true;
    }
  }
```

Here's what my console looks like:

[image]

Comment: You can also do this with ng-show/ng-hide or ng-if .

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable the `li` itself.

You can either disable the anchor tag (`a`) in it for example like this ([refernece](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13004761/9038475)):

```
document.getElementById("tab_c").childNodes[0].onclick = function() {return false;};​
```

**Or** you can set `pointer-events:none`as it has been done using CSS ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643505/how-can-i-disable-a-specific-li-element-inside-a-ul)):

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events:none; //This makes it not clickable
    opacity:0.6;         //This grays it out to look disabled
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.