# How to operate on a list item carried over from one div to another empty div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started learning JavaScript.
I have a problem. I'm trying to do the following:

I have two div's. Left populated with list,

.php code

```
<ul class="master">
    <?php foreach ($zabiegi as $zabieg): 
        echo '<button class="down" style="display: none;">Down</button>'.'<li>'.$zabieg['nazwa'].'</li>'.'<button class="up" style="display: none;">Up</button>';
    endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

html

```
<ul class="master">
    <li><button class="down" style="display: none;">Down</button></li>
    <li>First</li>
    <li><button class="up" style="display: none;">Up</button></li>
    <li><button class="down" style="display: none;">Down</button></li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li><button class="up" style="display: none;">Up</button></li>
    <li><button class="down" style="display: none;">Down</button></li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li><button class="up" style="display: none;">Up</button></li>
</ul>
```

and right empty. I'm trying to achieve the following effect. When you click in the left `div` element, you copy the item to the right `div`. 
Then, when clicked on an item copied to the right `div` I want to show up 2 buttons (elements, whatever) called `UP`, `DOWN` (I should look like `[Down] [Li] [Up]` ). When you click on one of them (up, down), adequate element to which they are assigned will be shifted by one 
position up or down.

I do not want to use draggable (jquery-ui), I would like to perform this task on the basis of simple clicks

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a side note, the `button` elements should be contained within your `li` since only `li` is allowed in a `ul`. See this SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209699/does-everything-inside-a-ul-have-to-be-wrapped-in-an-li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find a very crude but working example below, you'll be able to clean it up if you decide to use something based on this, thanks.

You can also see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/XqE3p/

```
<ul id="master">
  <li>
    First
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    Second
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    Third
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
(function() {

  // get the UL
  var ul = document.getElementById('master');

  // remove whitespace from in-between the <li>s
  // so that eg element.previousSibling always refers
  // to an <li> and not to eg "    "
  for(var i = 0, child = null; i < ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
    // get each child
    child = ul.childNodes[i];
    // if it's not an element, like an <li>
    if(child.nodeType !== 1) {
      // remove it
      ul.removeChild(child);
    }
  }

  function moveUp(li) {
    // if the li isn't already at the top
    if(li !== ul.firstChild) {
      // move it up one
      ul.insertBefore(li, li.previousSibling);
    }
  }

  function moveDown(li) {
    // if the li isn't already at the bottom
    if(li !== ul.lastChild) {
      // move the li below it up by one, moving us down
      moveUp(li.nextSibling);
    }
  }

  // listen for clicks
  ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // the clicked element
    var el = e.target;
    // it's class=""
    var elType = el.className;
    // any element with class="up"
    var isUpButton = elType.search(/\bup\b/) !== -1;
    // any element with class="down"
    var isDownButton = elType.search(/\bdown\b/) !== -1;

    if(isUpButton) {
      moveUp(el.parentNode);
    }
    if(isDownButton) {
      moveDown(el.parentNode);
    }
  });
}());
</script>
```

Comment: I didnt use your JavaScript code, but you helped me a lot with this HTML code... Thanks for the idea